# getting memory allocation error using normalize function/opencv and c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, normalization

To do normalization using opencv I am using this function:

```
cvNormalize(Src.data, Src.data, 255, 0, CV_MINMAX);
```

type of the input(Src) is Mat...to be able to use it as a pointer I have used `.data` but I get memory allocation error when I try this function...

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *What* memory allocation error? How does this error manifest itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the cv::normalize function. cvNormalize is deprecated.

```
cv::normalize(Src, Src, 255, 0, CV_MINMAX);
```